# React Timer + Color Change

Tags: reactjs, timer, colors

i have a simple div element in react, now i would like to be able to preset a time somewhere and for example after 10 minutes. The div would change color.

Does anyone know if that is possible to achieven?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `componentDidMount` API to init timer, and don't forget to remove it at `componentWillUnmount`.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      color: 'blue'
    }
  }

  handleChangeColor = (newColor) => {
    this.setState({
      color: newColor
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setTimeout(
      () => this.handleChangeColor('red'),
      1000*3 // in milliseconds, 3s for fast show
    )
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={ { background: this.state.color} }>
        Color Div
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

For full code, check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6fwotu).

Comment: is it also possible to start the timer from a preset ? like for example i preset the timer at 7 minutes to start with and then at 10 it will change?

Comment: If you really want to do so, you could wrap the setTimeout into a function and make a new setTimeout listener to call that function after 7 mins. [Check here for more information about setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).